# API Integration / Body error : Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set

Tags: apex, api, json

I'm trying to integrate an API to Salesforce and I don't why I've got this error when I'm trying my code :
" Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set "
I've searched on internet to fix it but nothing is working in my case.
Can you help me please ?

This is a part of my code, if needed I can send you more :)

```java
public  WS_OctobatTaxEvidenceResponseToApex getTaxEvidenceForSupplier(TaxEvidenceForSupplierRequestWrp wrp,  String userName , String  password)
{
    WS_OctobatTaxEvidenceResponseToApex retval = null;
    try
    {

        String jsonBody = JSON.serialize(wrp, true);

        String url = 'https://nippur-7009.quadernoapp.com/api/tax_rates/calculate';

        HttpResponse response = doHttpRequest(url,'GET',jsonBody, 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', userName , password );

        String responseBody = response.getBody();   
        
        retVal= (WS_OctobatTaxEvidenceResponseToApex)JSON.deserialize(responseBody, List<WS_OctobatTaxEvidenceResponseToApex>.class);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.debug(ex.getMessage());
        ccrz.ccLog.log(System.LoggingLevel.DEBUG,'octobat catch response',ex.getMessage());
    }
    return retval;
}
```

The JSON that I'm trying to work with :

```js
{
    "country": "FR",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "name": "TVA",
    "notes": null,
    "product_type": "service",
    "rate": 20.0,
    "region": null,
    "tax_behavior": "exclusive",
    "tax_code": "eservice",
    "taxable_part": 100.0,
    "import": false,
    "subtotal": 100.0,
    "tax_amount": 20.0,
    "total_amount": 120.0,
    "status": "taxable"
}
```

And the file WS_OctobatTaxEvidenceResponseToApex :

```java
public class WS_OctobatTaxEvidenceResponseToApex {

    public Decimal applied_rate{get;set;}

    public cls_tax_details[] tax_details{get;set;} 

    public cls_tax_id_validation tax_id_validation{get;set;}

    public class cls_tax_details {
        public Decimal rate{get;set;}   
        public String tax{get;set;} 
        public String tax_name{get;set;}    
        public String name{get;set;}
        public String tax_code{get;set;}
        public boolean reduced{get;set;}
    }

    public class cls_tax_id_validation {
        public String id{get;set;}  
        public String objectTax{get;set;}   
        public String tax_id{get;set;}
        public String type{get;set;}
        public boolean is_valid{get;set;}
    }
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the JSON that you're trying to work with. Seeing the `WS_OctobatTaxEvidenceResponseToApex` class is also going to be important here (so we can see if your deserialization classes are close to being fine or if they need attention too).

Comment: Start by `System.debug('budy=' + responseBody);`; a common cause of this sort of problem is that the response is an authentication failure. Also add `System.debug('code=' + response.getStatusCode());` and Google what the code means if its not in the range >= 200 and < 300.

Comment: @DerekF I edited my question with my JSON and WS_Octobat... file

Comment: @KeithC I tried this and I've got a status 500

Comment: I was asking for the JSON that you're getting back from the callout, not what you're providing to the third party that you're making the callout to. Though I suppose getting an HTTP 500 answers the question of why you're having trouble with deserializing the response (because the response isn't JSON at all). Your task here is to look at the documentation for `nippur-7009.quadernoapp.com` to see what you're doing wrong in making your request to them.

Answer (score 1):

```java
retVal= (WS_OctobatTaxEvidenceResponseToApex)JSON.deserialize(responseBody, List<WS_OctobatTaxEvidenceResponseToApex>.class);
```

`retVal` is defined as a single object, but here you're trying to deserialize the JSON to a List of object then cast it to a single one.
Even if the JSON had been deserializable to a List, it would have thrown an exception due to the cast.

Since the JSON string starts with a `{`, it means that it's a single object, so that line should be:

```java
retVal= (WS_OctobatTaxEvidenceResponseToApex)JSON.deserialize(responseBody, WS_OctobatTaxEvidenceResponseToApex.class);
```

That's why you got the error

> Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set

Anyway the class `WS_OctobatTaxEvidenceResponseToApex` has only three properties and none of them are inlcuded in the JSON, therefore after the deserialization every property would be null.

To hold every JSON property the class should look like this:

```java
public class WS_OctobatTaxEvidenceResponseToApex {
    public String country {get;set;} 
    public String currency_z {get;set;} // currency is a reserved keyword
    public String name {get;set;} 
    public String notes {get;set;} 
    public String product_type {get;set;} 
    public Decimal rate {get;set;} 
    public String region {get;set;} 
    public String tax_behavior {get;set;} 
    public String tax_code {get;set;} 
    public Decimal taxable_part {get;set;} 
    public Boolean import_z {get;set;} // import is a reserved keyword
    public Decimal subtotal {get;set;} 
    public Decimal tax_amount {get;set;} 
    public Decimal total_amount {get;set;} 
    public String status {get;set;}
}
```

[Reserved keywords](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_reserved_words.htm) cannot be used as property's name, that's why the class has `currency_z` instead of `currency`, so, before deserialize that string you have to replace those keywords with valid identifier:

```java
responseBody = responseBody.replace('"currency"', '"currency_z"').replace('"import"', '"import_z"');
retVal= (WS_OctobatTaxEvidenceResponseToApex)JSON.deserialize(responseBody, WS_OctobatTaxEvidenceResponseToApex.class);
```

Now `retVal` will hold the JSON data